# add new postgres server in pgadmin on docker

Tags: postgresql, docker, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

i'm new to docker and postgres. i configured the postgres and pgadmin4 service containers and i want to create a new server in pgadmin. i get the ip of the postgres container by inspect instruction as 172.18.0.2

my postgres inspect result is as follows:

```
            [
                {
                    "Id": "8a898f76c4ed5bc9e003c5d0be8ab67f7f7045fe1cc4c1cb82cc263136360c0a",
                    "Created": "2020-02-11T22:54:11.018152083Z",
                    "Path": "docker-entrypoint.sh",
                    "Args": [
                        "postgres"
                    ],
                    "State": {
                        "Status": "running",
                        "Running": true,
                        "Paused": false,
                        "Restarting": false,
                        "OOMKilled": false,
                        "Dead": false,
                        "Pid": 4078,
                        "ExitCode": 0,
                        "Error": "",
                        "StartedAt": "2020-02-27T07:53:43.570077899Z",
                        "FinishedAt": "2020-02-27T07:35:12.205132013Z"
                    },
                    "Image": "sha256:b43856647ab572f271decd1f8de88b590e157bfd816599362fe162e8f37fb1ec",
                    "ResolvConfPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/8a898f76c4ed5bc9e003c5d0be8ab67f7f7045fe1cc4c1cb82cc263136360c0a/resolv.conf",
                    "HostnamePath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/8a898f76c4ed5bc9e003c5d0be8ab67f7f7045fe1cc4c1cb82cc263136360c0a/hostname",
                    "HostsPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/8a898f76c4ed5bc9e003c5d0be8ab67f7f7045fe1cc4c1cb82cc263136360c0a/hosts",
                    "LogPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/8a898f76c4ed5bc9e003c5d0be8ab67f7f7045fe1cc4c1cb82cc263136360c0a/8a898f76c4ed5bc9e003c5d0be8ab67f7f7045fe1cc4c1cb82cc263136360c0a-json.log",
                    "Name": "/google-ad-words-postgres",
                    "RestartCount": 0,
                    "Driver": "overlay2",
                    "Platform": "linux",
                    "MountLabel": "",
                    "ProcessLabel": "",
                    "AppArmorProfile": "",
                    "ExecIDs": null,
                    "HostConfig": {
                        "Binds": [
                            "/host_mnt/c/wamp64/www/google-ad-words:/application:rw"
                        ],
                        "ContainerIDFile": "",
                        "LogConfig": {
                            "Type": "json-file",
                            "Config": {}
                        },
                        "NetworkMode": "google-ad-words_default",
                        "PortBindings": {
                            "5432/tcp": [
                                {
                                    "HostIp": "",
                                    "HostPort": "8084"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "RestartPolicy": {
                            "Name": "",
                            "MaximumRetryCount": 0
                        },
                        "AutoRemove": false,
                        "VolumeDriver": "",
                        "VolumesFrom": [],
                        "CapAdd": null,
                        "CapDrop": null,
                        "Capabilities": null,
                        "Dns": [],
                        "DnsOptions": [],
                        "DnsSearch": [],
                        "ExtraHosts": null,
                        "GroupAdd": null,
                        "IpcMode": "shareable",
                        "Cgroup": "",
                        "Links": null,
                        "OomScoreAdj": 0,
                        "PidMode": "",
                        "Privileged": false,
                        "PublishAllPorts": false,
                        "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
                        "SecurityOpt": null,
                        "UTSMode": "",
                        "UsernsMode": "",
                        "ShmSize": 67108864,
                        "Runtime": "runc",
                        "ConsoleSize": [
                            0,
                            0
                        ],
                        "Isolation": "",
                        "CpuShares": 0,
                        "Memory": 0,
                        "NanoCpus": 0,
                        "CgroupParent": "",
                        "BlkioWeight": 0,
                        "BlkioWeightDevice": null,
                        "BlkioDeviceReadBps": null,
                        "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": null,
                        "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": null,
                        "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": null,
                        "CpuPeriod": 0,
                        "CpuQuota": 0,
                        "CpuRealtimePeriod": 0,
                        "CpuRealtimeRuntime": 0,
                        "CpusetCpus": "",
                        "CpusetMems": "",
                        "Devices": null,
                        "DeviceCgroupRules": null,
                        "DeviceRequests": null,
                        "KernelMemory": 0,
                        "KernelMemoryTCP": 0,
                        "MemoryReservation": 0,
                        "MemorySwap": 0,
                        "MemorySwappiness": null,
                        "OomKillDisable": false,
                        "PidsLimit": null,
                        "Ulimits": null,
                        "CpuCount": 0,
                        "CpuPercent": 0,
                        "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
                        "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0,
                        "MaskedPaths": [
                            "/proc/asound",
                            "/proc/acpi",
                            "/proc/kcore",
                            "/proc/keys",
                            "/proc/latency_stats",
                            "/proc/timer_list",
                            "/proc/timer_stats",
                            "/proc/sched_debug",
                            "/proc/scsi",
                            "/sys/firmware"
                        ],
                        "ReadonlyPaths": [
                            "/proc/bus",
                            "/proc/fs",
                            "/proc/irq",
                            "/proc/sys",
                            "/proc/sysrq-trigger"
                        ]
                    },
                    "GraphDriver": {
                        "Data": {
                            "LowerDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/579907e185eaf689fe2fa0e75c7ccd207fd05f85154bda4887c836d60062c276-init/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/0f235c1ebc1aad578ab2998c9727c8002c883e83f6076b325b69b16ed31f35eb/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/3eab87840cf262453f6fa744c4ae61b77a26e75fcd48f4388f36120a70a680e7/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/22e70ec746122772356fe213b9149f063c4eb97a5185c7dee8cb7c1ca1648086/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/2fa1dbd50eba44c7e7c3c3c79c65467f0c754927750d691cd32253c048baf840/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/5588b603da1c7139c0ff79edd158fa2579166156849c85457ce1ef9542d6be0f/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/a3c4096b7b08d323bad09f959b23c7ed96764fc90569528ba0774b9ce63d0013/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/800f19b5767d6598088c8ac4d64e6bab0421226665db0e505e3500563284d668/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/67e3730eeaeac3411e5d54eb6cd34c6e5fa486138d0e0d9e1bf135336ef7ccc6/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/0b092310839803394dd4a830ae2143930d47f8e86173cb46bd4a3e29f4ec87cb/diff",
                            "MergedDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/579907e185eaf689fe2fa0e75c7ccd207fd05f85154bda4887c836d60062c276/merged",
                            "UpperDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/579907e185eaf689fe2fa0e75c7ccd207fd05f85154bda4887c836d60062c276/diff",
                            "WorkDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/579907e185eaf689fe2fa0e75c7ccd207fd05f85154bda4887c836d60062c276/work"
                        },
                        "Name": "overlay2"
                    },
                    "Mounts": [
                        {
                            "Type": "bind",
                            "Source": "/host_mnt/c/wamp64/www/google-ad-words",
                            "Destination": "/application",
                            "Mode": "rw",
                            "RW": true,
                            "Propagation": "rprivate"
                        },
                        {
                            "Type": "volume",
                            "Name": "3b62664927156c94ba1f570c4082246755f1b66f6f4dd3ea6e00e7f84099bee9",
                            "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/3b62664927156c94ba1f570c4082246755f1b66f6f4dd3ea6e00e7f84099bee9/_data",
                            "Destination": "/var/lib/postgresql/data",
                            "Driver": "local",
                            "Mode": "",
                            "RW": true,
                            "Propagation": ""
                        }
                    ],
                    "Config": {
                        "Hostname": "8a898f76c4ed",
                        "Domainname": "",
                        "User": "",
                        "AttachStdin": false,
                        "AttachStdout": false,
                        "AttachStderr": false,
                        "ExposedPorts": {
                            "5432/tcp": {}
                        },
                        "Tty": false,
                        "OpenStdin": false,
                        "StdinOnce": false,
                        "Env": [
                            "POSTGRES_USER=root",
                            "POSTGRES_PASSWORD=toor",
                            "POSTGRES_DB=core-db",
                            "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                            "LANG=en_US.utf8",
                            "PG_MAJOR=11",
                            "PG_VERSION=11.1",
                            "PG_SHA256=90815e812874831e9a4bf6e1136bf73bc2c5a0464ef142e2dfea40cda206db08",
                            "PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data"
                        ],
                        "Cmd": [
                            "postgres"
                        ],
                        "Image": "postgres:11.1-alpine",
                        "Volumes": {
                            "/application": {},
                            "/var/lib/postgresql/data": {}
                        },
                        "WorkingDir": "/application",
                        "Entrypoint": [
                            "docker-entrypoint.sh"
                        ],
                        "OnBuild": null,
                        "Labels": {
                            "com.docker.compose.config-hash": "b42b467fdb058676db6aac2de623ca4dc24d602d25bdbe5538f03270d1394dda",
                            "com.docker.compose.container-number": "1",
                            "com.docker.compose.oneoff": "False",
                            "com.docker.compose.project": "google-ad-words",
                            "com.docker.compose.project.config_files": "docker-compose.yml",
                            "com.docker.compose.project.working_dir": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\google-ad-words",
                            "com.docker.compose.service": "postgres",
                            "com.docker.compose.version": "1.25.4"
                        }
                    },
                    "NetworkSettings": {
                        "Bridge": "",
                        "SandboxID": "b6e5d1edca6b3dd27ca26fa038747fb08926dec8b9a8594d1d6160998f1caaa0",
                        "HairpinMode": false,
                        "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
                        "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                        "Ports": {
                            "5432/tcp": [
                                {
                                    "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                                    "HostPort": "8084"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/b6e5d1edca6b",
                        "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
                        "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
                        "EndpointID": "",
                        "Gateway": "",
                        "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                        "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                        "IPAddress": "",
                        "IPPrefixLen": 0,
                        "IPv6Gateway": "",
                        "MacAddress": "",
                        "Networks": {
                            "google-ad-words_default": {
                                "IPAMConfig": null,
                                "Links": null,
                                "Aliases": [
                                    "postgres",
                                    "8a898f76c4ed"
                                ],
                                "NetworkID": "340ce7b63f7790542cd04ec8ff7f55cd5847f38d113f6e444e369919e6fc44fb",
                                "EndpointID": "bc62ec297e23d83ae468fe76d2ca12647c594521f445d6d5a2fbed658481fa1a",
                                "Gateway": "172.18.0.1",
                                "IPAddress": "172.18.0.2",
                                "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                                "IPv6Gateway": "",
                                "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                                "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:02",
                                "DriverOpts": null
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
```

when i want to add the server from pgadmin, i got the following error.
[timeout expired error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1ML0.png).
how can i resolve this?
thanks...

Comment: can you provide `docker-compose.yml` or how your start all of it

Comment: @Jean-JacquesMOIROUX this is all of my docker-compose.yml contents:
http://nkwall.ir/docker-compose.yml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

syntax was weird on environments. Create a .env file with your secrets inside, then load it from docker-compose

.env

```
PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=pgadmin4@pgadmin.org
PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=admin
PGADMIN_PORT=5050
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.1"
services:

    memcached:
      image: memcached:alpine
      container_name: google-ad-words-memcached

    postgres:
      image: postgres:11.1-alpine
      container_name: google-ad-words-postgres
      working_dir: /application
      volumes:
        - .:/application  # prefer absolute path on host
      environment:
        - POSTGRES_USER=root
        - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=toor
        - POSTGRES_DB=core-db
      ports:
        - "8084:5432"
      networks:     # <-- Add this line
        - postgres  # <-- Add this line

    pgadmin:
      image: dpage/pgadmin4
      container_name: pgadmin_container
      working_dir: /application
      env_file: # <-- Add this line
        - .env  # <-- Add this line
      volumes:
        - pgadmin:/root/.pgadmin
      environment:
        # - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL:-pgadmin4@pgadmin.org}  # <-- Wrong this
        # - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD:-admin}           # <-- Wrong this
        - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL}        # <-- Right this
        - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD}  # <-- Right this
      ports:
        # - "${PGADMIN_PORT:-5050}:80"  # <-- Wrong this
        - "${PGADMIN_PORT}:80"          # <-- Right this
      networks:
        - postgres
      restart: unless-stopped

    webserver:
      image: nginx:alpine
      container_name: google-ad-words-webserver
      working_dir: /application
      volumes:
          - .:/application    # prefer absolute path on host
          - ./phpdocker/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf # prefer absolute path on host
      ports:
       - "8080:80"

    php-fpm:
      build: phpdocker/php-fpm
      container_name: google-ad-words-php-fpm
      working_dir: /application
      volumes:
        - .:/application      # prefer absolute path on host
        - ./phpdocker/php-fpm/php-ini-overrides.ini:/etc/php/7.4/fpm/conf.d/99-overrides.ini  # prefer absolute path on host

networks:
  postgres:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  postgres:
  #pgadmin:  # <-- Not used, remove it
```

Comment: I tried something similar to this but using `./config.env` instead of `.env`. I got errors about variables not being set. [It turns out](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/6581#issuecomment-540638939) that in general, `env_file:` only sets variables in the *runtime* environment (in the container), so can't be used to fill `${my_var}` in the yaml file. `.env` is special and gets read and set before the yaml file is parsed. (It actually doesn't even need an `env_file:` entry at all). This is why it can be used to fill `${my_var}`